# .NET Application_BeginRequest - How to get User reference?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I'm trying to get a reference to the user object in my Global.asax file's `Application_BeginRequest`. I'm using the property `Context.User` but I get a `NullReferenceException`. **Is it possible to get a user object reference in Application_BeginRequest?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't have access to the User object because the request hasn't yet been authenticated.

Try using Application_AuthenticateRequest instead.

Here is an explanation of all Global.asax events:
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5771721.html

And the MSDN walkthrough of the application lifecycle:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

Edit: 
I see what you're doing.  Change your if statement to and if not statement (sorry if syntax is wrong, I don't use VB.NET):

```
 Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest() 
   If Context.User <> Nothing Then 
      Throw New Exception("User now exists") 
 End Sub
```

You'll notice that this method gets hit more than once.  The exception won't be thrown until the second or third time.  That is because every request follows the application lifecycle.  So, instead of performing whatever action when the user is null, you should perform it when the user is not null.

**If your goal is to restrict access dynamically, you should create a separate HttpModule and assign it to the files you're restricting**

However, you'll need to be careful not to undertake rewriting the entire ASP.NET Application Security infrastructure.  You can, instead, restrict access to certain folders based on role.

Comment: Please check my comment in the other answer by Julien... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072768/net-application-beginrequest-how-to-get-user-reference/3072801#3072801

Comment: ropstah: I see now what is happening.  The application is making multiple requests (maybe for images, scripts, stylesheets, etc.) before the authentication request is processed.  Those other file requests may not need authentication and that is why your exception is being thrown. Try the update in my answer and see if that clarifies.  Also, what are you trying to achieve with your code that requires the User object?

Comment: This was not the case, however it **was** related to the `Global.asax` lifecycle. I needed the `User.IsInRole()` functionality which was only available **after** _Application_AuthenticateRequest_ namely in the procedure `Application_AuthorizeRequest()`

Answer (score 10):

No, you must use `Application_AuthenticateRequest` instead. That's the earliest point where you have an user.

Comment: This throws an exception, still no user or what?
Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest()
    If Context.User Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("No user")
End Sub