# asp.net Login control and the logged user in the global.asax

Tags: asp.net, login-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Application_BeginRequest - How to get User reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072768/net-application-beginrequest-how-to-get-user-reference)

I have problem with my asp Login control. I have set the Forms authentication mode in my web.config file, and I want to get the logged user data in the global.asax -> Application_BeginRequest method.

.aspx code snippet:

```
  <asp:Login OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" ID="LoginUser" runat="server">
     [...]
  </asp:Login>

    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.RememberMeSet);
        }
    }
```

The global.asax code snippet

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var usr = HttpContext.Current.User;
    }
```

the `HttpContext.Current.User` property is null - why ?

Answer (score 1):

Umm.. because the user is not yet authenticated?  Application_BeginRequest is called at the very beginning of the request, before anything else has happened, such as validating the authentication cookie.

Why do you need to do this in BeginRequest?