# ASP.NET MVC dependency injection in application events

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection

I've a follow up question to:
[ASP.NET MVC, set culture after authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701065/asp-net-mvc-set-culture-after-authorization)

Our dependency injection composition root is ASP.NET MVC's `MvcApplication.Application_Start` method. We're also registering for ASP.NET's `PostAuthenticateRequest` application event in `MvcApplication.Init`.

We now need to inject an instance of `IUserSettingsRepository` into our `OnPostAuthenticateRequest` event handler. How to do that?

Note: we don't want to put a static field into our `MvcApplication` class, as this is a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Dependency Injection solution is well integrated with ASP.NET MVC, you could simply refer to it using `DependencyResolver.Current`. for example:

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserSettingsRepository>();
```

(Strictly speaking, it's not really 'injecting an instance' but rather resolving the dependency using 'Service Locator' approach)

Comment: Yes, we are integrated into ASP.NET MVC and considered this solution before, however, we've not been 100% satisfied. If there is any other better solution we would appreciate it :-)

Comment: You need to resolve `IUserSettingsRepository` and you claim that you're using an IoC, what would be the reason not to use the Container to resolve the dependency?

Comment: @D.R. Service location is the only alternative. It's how MVC do it internally for everything. SL is not an anti pattern as many claim. (I've blogged about it: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/09/service-locator-is-not-an-anti-pattern/)